# What is the difference between (&v).func() and &v.func()?

Tags: rust, iterator

What is `(&v)` actually doing in this code?

```rust
let v = vec!["hello", "viktor"];
let mut iterator = (&v).into_iter(); // Iter<&str>
```

```rust
let mut iterator = &v.into_iter(); // &IntoIter<&str>
```

How it is changing what is returned from `.into_iter()`. Why is the result different?

Comment: NIT: if the intent of writing `(&v).into_iter()` is to get an iterator of references to `v`, then it is best written as `v.iter()`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a precedence issue. With `&v.into_iter()`, the compiler understands `&(v.into_iter())` not `(&v).into_iter()`, just like when you write `1+2*3`, the compiler understands `1+(2*3)`, and not `(1+2)*3`.